# How to convert json array to json object in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have this query

```
select p.name,
to_json(
    array(
      select json_build_object(
        pm.project_member_id,  json_build_object(
          'user', concat(u.firstname , ' ', u.lastname), 'role', r."name", 'team', t."name"
        )
      )
      from project_members pm 
      left join users u 
      on u.user_id = pm.user_id 
      left join roles r 
      on r.role_id = pm.role_id 
      where pm.project_id = 'pid1'
    )
) member
from projects p
where p.project_id = 'pid1';
```

And have this result:

| name | member |
| --- | --- |
| project1 | [{"id1" : {"user" : "Ailene", "role" : "Manager" }},{"id2" : {"user" : "Andres", "role" : "Developer"}}] |

Is there a way to convert the array of objects to a flat object?

example:

```json
{
  "id1": { "user": "Ailene , "role": "Manager" },
  "id2": { "user": "Andres", "role": "Developer" }
}
```

How is this possible using a query? Or do I have to do this in a client and modify the data after obtaining the query results?

Comment: You are looking for `jsonb_object_agg()`

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm quite new to this aggregate functions in postgres. but can you provide the query using `jsonb_object_agg`?